# wenzhixin bootstrap-table unable to click on select2

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2, bootstrap-table

Here is the problem, and a put together a mockup in Codeply http://www.codeply.com/go/rxWzeVwBUa.

I am unable to click on the Select2 dropdown box withing the datatable. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <div class="container">
        <h1>From data</h1>
        <p></p>
        <table id="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="id">ID</th>
                <th data-field="name">Item Name
                    <select class='table finditem'>
                        <option></option>
                        <option value='0'>Item 0</option>
                        ...
                    </select>
                </th>
                <th data-field="price">Item Price</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>

        $table.bootstrapTable({
            data: data});
        });


        $('#finditem').select2({
            placeholder: 'Find Item',
            allowClear: true
        });
```

Comment: Do you use `id="finditem"` in one element and `class="finditem"` in the other? Is that intentional? Anyway, only the one with class will be activated at the moment, since you use jquery selector `.finditem`.

Comment: sorry, not intentional, it was originally just an ID that was converted to a class for the example. on the link it is included as a class also, so it initializes correctly.

Comment: Your code looks ok. It seems that the two plugins don't play well together. I suppose the bootstrap-table hijacks your click and doesn't let it bubble to the select2-element.

Comment: that was my thought was well. I have them in a toolbar above the table for the time being, but getting select2 formated properly with bootstrap is another nightmare entirely. I'm hoping not to have to deal with that one (and it is a lot cleaner if I can put it in the table header).

Answer (score 1):

I posted this to the developer on github and the developer posted the solution;

https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/1254#issuecomment-130358202
http://www.codeply.com/go/e4LJoKfhdR

```
$table.on('post-header.bs.table', function () {
    $('.finditem').select2({
        placeholder: 'Find Item',
        allowClear: true
    });
});
```

Incidentally I found out if you want to use any select2 event listeners they also have to be placed within this function also. I use a series of cascading select2 boxes to automatically update the table when they selected.

```
    $table.on('post-header.bs.table', function () {
        $('.finditem').select2({
            placeholder: 'Find Item',
            allowClear: true
        });
        $('.finditem').on('select2:close', function(){
            $table.bootstrapTable('refresh');
        });
    });
```