# JQuery code is not executed when bootstrap-table column list displayed changes

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have a bootstrap-table which have a not visible column at start: data-visible="false". The columns caption contains a button to display a modal help dialog:

```
<script>

    // This is repeated for each column that have help button, 
    // some are visible at the start and some not.
    $("#helpButtonColumnX").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation(); // Prevent ordering by the field 
                                 // when the button is pressed.
        console.log("Hey"); // Do something
        $('#modalDialogColumnX').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that when the user changes which columns want to see this functionality is loss. (The console.log is for debugging, and is confirmed that the function is not called).
Each column has his own button and modal, i put an X as an example.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:[here a codeply](http://www.codeply.com/go/HeTKpgL0ej)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know enough about `boostrap-table`, it's possible that boostrap-table is adding/removing html and that will cause any events on the table to stop working (as the html is added *after* the event has been wired).

A quick look at the [docs](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/documentation.html#events) shows there's an `onColumnSwitch` event.

This gives you two options:

1 Re-add your click handler by adding an event handle for the `onColumnSwitch` event, eg something like:

```
$("#table").on("column-switch.bs.table", function() {
     // this would be easier if you put it in a separate function 
     // then you could call it from here and startup
     $("#helpButtonColumnX").click(function(event) {
     ...
     });
});
```

2 Use event delegation rather than wire up events directly, eg:

```
$("document").on("click", "#helpButtonColumnX", function() {
    ...
});
```

The second option might be your best bet, but has (some minor) performance issues (that you probably won't notice).

Comment: After trying both solutions give me the same results: the functionality is loss even before the column selection. I don't know if the chrome or firefox document explorer shows the active code but I see the code there, but is not called.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this solution would work for you? I had a similar problem with clicking on select2 boxes in a column header. The bootstrap-table author provided a solution that [I posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31949354/wenzhixin-bootstrap-table-unable-to-click-on-select2).

Comment: As I comment in the previous solution, both suggestions didn't work (also breaks the functionality before the column selection).

Comment: I will play with it when I get some time, it may be later this evening or maybe even tomorrow evening.

Comment: on your codeply I'm not seeing the buttons in the column headers etc. is the codeply a functional working example showing the bug you are having?

Comment: The button is in the not displayed at start column named Price. Regads

Comment: ok - this is way this would be applied with the example I posted. I added ID to the table, and then put it all inside of the wrapper I mentioned. http://www.codeply.com/go/FiMTCSTrEk

Comment: In your example I see: That the headers are dispayed twice, the top header is ordering when I press the button (that is what I'm trying to avoid) and that the data is not displayed.

Comment: all I was showing was how to implement `.on('post-header.bs.table'`. Since are not providing a data source, or data, and then trying to also add rows it is duplicating the header. I removed your rows and your div tags in the header. (saved the example with the updates).

as to sorting I don't see any attempt to try and disable sort;

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/
event.stopPropagation() from the jQuery webpage
"Note that this will not prevent other handlers on the same element from running."